# How to interpolate with variables in pug?

Tags: express, pug

I have a pug view

```
section#about.about
        .container
            .about__inner
                .about__content
                    h3.about__title About me
                    h2.about__bigtitle Who am I
                    .about__text !{about}
                    a.btn(href="#" data-modal="#modal_hire_me") Hire me
                    button.btn(type="button" data-modal="#modal_resume") My resume
```

In express server I render it with "about", "works" and "reviewsAmount" variables.
The "about" variable value is

```
    const about = `
            <p>
                I have #{works.length} works and #{reviewsAmount} reviews.
            </p>
        `;
```

But in page it renders like "I have #{works.length} works and #{reviewsAmount} reviews.". Variable values do not interpolate in paragraph tag. So, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing up [pug interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) and JavaScript [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).  When the code is in your node/express route (and not in the template) you need to use JavaScript template strings.

If you use the `${}` syntax this will fix it.

```
const about = `
        <p>
            I have ${works.length} works and ${reviewsAmount} reviews.
        </p>
    `;
```

With that said, I'd recommend against doing this and leaving all of your HTML in pug and not moving it into the node/express code.  This will make your web pages more difficult to debug when something goes wrong, and also require more effort to maintain longer term.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass those variables on to Pug and do the interpolation there:

```
section#about.about
  .container
    .about__inner
      .about__content
        h3.about__title About me
        h2.about__bigtitle Who am I
        .about__text
          p I have #{works.length} works and #{reviewsAmount} reviews.
        a.btn(href="#" data-modal="#modal_hire_me") Hire me
        button.btn(type="button" data-modal="#modal_resume") My resume
```

Comment: Your idea is not what I need. I create admin panel for my self project and "about" variable I will set from admin panel.

Comment: Graham's answer should address that concern then.